# CNN - Is this a Toeplitz Matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, matrix

I have been reading through Chapter 9 of [www.deeplearningbbook.org](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html), where convolutional networks are being described.

The following image represents the output of a 2D convolution, without kernel flipping.

[image]

The book goes on to describe this matrix as a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) where,

> for univariate discrete convolution, each row of the matrix is constrained to be
>   equal to the row above shifted by one element.

I fully understand this statement since `w`, `x`, `y` and `z` are constants in their respective columns with shifting elements.

However, there is no mention of **diagonal-constants** which are a key feature of such matrices. As per Wikipedia (link above) and several other sources:

> a Toeplitz matrix or diagonal-constant matrix, named after Otto Toeplitz, is a matrix in which each descending diagonal from left to right is constant.

Going back to the image above, does this mean that, for instance, `aw == cx == gy`? How can this be ensured when all elements are different?

Answer (score 4):

The matrices in that picture are not toeplitz matrices. Rather, convolution can be *treated* as matrix multiplication by a toeplitz matrix.

For example, to convolve $x = [1, 3, 1, 0]^T$ by the filter [5, 1, 1], you first construct the toeplitz matrix:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $Mx$ computes the convolution (technically correlation!) of $x$ by the filter. Clearly $M$ is toeplitz.

Comment: But what about a 2D case?

Comment: @bombs see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411498/representation-of-a-convolutional-layer-as-a-fully-connected-one-matrix-represe