# representation of a convolutional layer as a fully connected one (matrix representation)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, matrix

I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate, but Google seems to confirm that this is indeed the case.

What is the representation of a convolutional layer as a fully connected layer? A convolutional layer is nothing else than a discrete convolution, thus it must be representable as a matrix$\times$vector product, where the matrix is sparse with some well-defined, cyclic structure. However, what are neurons in this case? In the usual FC layer representation, each neuron has a vector input and a scalar output. But $\mathbf{M}\cdot\mathbf{v}$ is a vector, not a scalar. I must be missing something obvious.

PS of course $\mathbf{M}$ is not the input image - if the input is RGB, $\mathbf{M}$ must be some matricial representation of three matrices (R, G and B). If instead we're talking about a hidden layer, then $\mathbf{M}$ is a representation as a matrix of dozens or hundreds of matrices (channels).

Comment: "In the usual FC layer representation, each layer has a vector input and a scalar output." -- isn't the output of an FC layer a vector?

Comment: @shimao yes, of course - I put the blame on autocompletion! Fixed.

Comment: @shimao Actually, I think a scalar output is the right word because it's a "one" neuron he is talking about.

Comment: @DeltaIV  ⋅ is not an output of an single neuron. It's an output of a single layer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the 1D, 1-channel case, you may be interested in a [related question and answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374716/cnn-is-this-a-toeplitz-matrix).

In the 2D case*, if we flatten the input to the convolution $x \in \mathbb{R}^{C\times H\times W}$ into a vector $x' \in \mathbb{R}^{CHW}$ in the usual manner (such that $x'_{iHW+jW+k} = x_{i,j,k}$), and we have a convolutional kernel $K \in \mathbb{R}^{D\times C\times P\times Q}$ ($D$ is the out dimension and each filter has receptive field $P$ by $Q$) then we can define a weight matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{DH'W' \times CHW}$ ($H'=H-P+1, W'=W-Q+1$)such that the flattened version of $y = \text{conv}(K,x)$ can be written as $y' = Mx'$ as follows:

$$
M_{s,t} = \begin{cases} K_{s,i,v-j,w-k} &\text{if } 0 \leq v-j < P \text{ and } 0 \leq w-k < Q\\ 0 &\text{otherwise } \end{cases}
$$

Where $i,j,k$ are defined by $t = iHW+jW+k$ and $j<H$, $k<W$. and $u,v,w$ are defined by $s = uH'W'+vW'+w$ and $v < H'$ and $w < W'$.

You can see in each row of $M$, corresponding to a single entry in the output feature map, the only nonzero entries of that row are in the columns corresponding to the appropriate input receptive field.

*well I'm not masochistic enough to deal with strides, dilation, padding, separable filters, etc in this answer.

> However, what are neurons in this case?

A neuron in a convolutional network (although I think it's usually not useful to think in terms of neurons), is a single entry in a feature (which is a vector) in a feature map (which is a 2D grid of features -- a 3D tensor).

---

Ok I agree the indexing notation is rather dense, here I'll write out an explicit example:

Our input $x$ is 1 by 3 by 3:

```
[
    [
        [1 2 3]
        [4 5 6]
        [7 8 9]
    ]
]
```

Each single value such as "1" or "5" here is a neuron.

We flatten this into the vector $x'$:

```
[1 2 3|4 5 6|7 8 9]
```

(to keep things sane, here and later, i use | to delimit every 3 elements, so you can see how they map onto the 1x3x3 input)

Meanwhile our kernel $K$ is 2 by 1 by 2 by 2:

```
[
    [
        [
            [a b]
            [c d]
        ]
    ]
    [
        [
            [e f]
            [g h]
        ]
    ]
]
```

We arrange this into the matrix $M$, which is 8 by 9:

```
[
    [a b 0|c d 0|0 0 0]
    [0 a b|0 c d|0 0 0]
    [0 0 0|a b 0|c d 0]
    [0 0 0|0 a b|0 c d]
    [e f 0|g h 0|0 0 0]
    [0 e f|0 g h|0 0 0]
    [0 0 0|e f 0|g h 0]
    [0 0 0|0 e f|0 g h]
]
```

Then $Mx' = y'$ computes

```
[1a+2b+4c+5d, 2a+3b+5c+6d, 4a+5b+7c+8d, 5a+6b+8c+9d, 1e+2f+4g+5h, 2e+3f+5g+6h, 4e+5f+7g+8h, 5e+6f+8g+9h]
```

Again as before, each scalar value here such as "1a+2b+4c+5d" is a single neuron.

We reshape this to 2 by 2 by 2 to recover $y$:

```
[
    [
        [1a+2b+4c+5d, 2a+3b+5c+6d]
        [4a+5b+7c+8d, 5a+6b+8c+9d]
    ]
    [
        [1e+2f+4g+5h, 2e+3f+5g+6h]
        [4e+5f+7g+8h, 5e+6f+8g+9h]
    ]
]
```

And you can see by inspection this is what we'd get by sliding the filter $K$ over the original $x$.

Comment: "I think it's usually not useful to think in terms of neurons" - it's actually indispensable if you want to understand the literature on visualization CNN hidden layers, because [the term is routinely used in that literature](https://distill.pub/2018/building-blocks/), pheraps unfortunately. Your answer is not clear to me - what is a neuron (or if you prefer, what are its inputs and output) in a CNN? In your notation, is the input $x'$ and the output $m_i\cdot x'$, i.e., one component of $y'$? Or to be more precise, is the neuron output $ReLU(y_i')=ReLU(m_i\cdot x')$?

Comment: it's a bit difficult (for me) to follow your notation. As an example, can you please write explicitly one or two (consecutive) rows of $M$? A simple case is fine - for example,  $K \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 1\times 3\times 3}$, and each of the 3 kernels is actually the same, for example, a sharpen kernel $[[0, -1, 0];[-1, 5, -1];[0, -1, 0]]$

Comment: Ps I’m  % with you about not dealing with strides, padding, etc. the basic 2D case is fine.

Comment: @DeltaIV I wrote out an explicit example -- hope it helps

Comment: interesting - thus in the nD case with $n>1$, $M$ is not even Toeplizt, right?

Comment: yeah, it's not.