# Can we express CNNs in terms of a MLP?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, perceptron

I have been wondering whether a convolution can be represented in terms of an MLP. We can say that in convolution we have shared parameters between different neurons. But how to express this mathematically?

More specifically, I want to know what kind of decision boundary does a convolution gives to us? Like A perceptron gives us a linear boundary, is there some way we can visualize convolution as giving a decision boundary?

Comment: good question, i think i had the same question for a while. the answer should be Yes, but how to make it nicely in math may be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411498/representation-of-a-convolutional-layer-as-a-fully-connected-one-matrix-represe) for the representation of a convolutional layer as a fully-connected one.

Since a convolutional layer is still a linear function in the inputs, then a convolutional layer followed by a average pool / softmax layer would still be linear.

For more complicated CNNs with commonly used relu activations and max-pooling layers, note that every component is still piece-wise linear. So the decision boundary is also piece-wise linear.

The main difficulty with visualizing this boundary is that images are very high dimensional, (almost 200K dimensions for a small 256x256 RGB image), so it's not really that feasible. You could use any number of dimensionality reducing / latent space embedding techniques to place each image in 2D-euclidean space, but this transformation is often non-linear (and thus your boundary would no longer be).